# Unable to select an Element using Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public void Test003() {
    new Select (webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select"))).selectByVisibleText("NEC_COCONA_GG3");

    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-menu']/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("issue_subject")).sendKeys("Test");
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("issue_description")).sendKeys("Test");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("issue_assigned_to_id"))).selectByVisibleText("<<me>>");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("issue_custom_field_values_7"))).selectByVisibleText("QA");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("issue_custom_field_values_27")).sendKeys("Test");
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='attachments_fields']/span/input[1]")).sendKeys("D:\\NEC new\\log\\EASCrash.txt");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='attachments_form']/span[2]/a")).click();
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='attachments_fields']/span[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("D:\\NEC new\\log\\crash_info_201304171712.txt");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='issue[watcher_user_ids][]' and @value='102']")).click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='issue-form']/input[1]")).click();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
}
```

While running the script selenium is unable to get the value of

```
new Select (webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select"))).selectByVisibleText("NEC_COCONA_GG3");
```

select for which the testcase in failing.

Error shown is:

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver does not support finding an element by selector: select
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to open a drop down menu and select an item inside it?

Comment: Also, what is "select"?

Comment: You don't have to set the implicit wait every time you're looking up an element. Simply set it once in the beginning and then forget about it, it will do its work. Also, 3 milliseconds is negligible and probably won't help.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser? Which one are you using, anyway?

Comment: wow.. this is one ridiculously ugly test.

Comment: @Scott Helme: Yes i am trying to select an item from drop down.

Comment: @ScottHelme: "select" is the cssSelector element name for the drop down box.

Comment: Same code is working fine on other machines.What can be the reason for this ?

Comment: @Slanec : I had put implicit wait every time to check the flow on the browser.I will be removing it in the longer run.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be stemming from multiple selects.  Are there any attributes that uniquely identify the select box?  if so, then you need to uniquely identify it.  If there is a name on it, then do

```
By.cssSelector("select[name='someName']");
```

A title would even work.

```
By.cssSelector("select[title^='Select your']");
```

If you have an open mind, try [this framework](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) out. (you can download it [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip).

Your test would be refactored to:

```
@Config(url="http://systemunder.test", browser=Browsers.CHROME)
public class MyTest extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void Test003() {
        selectOptionByText (By.cssSelector("select"))
        .click             (By.cssSelector("div#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a"))
        .setText           (By.id("issue_subject"), "Test")
        .setText           (By.id("issue_description"), "Test")
        .selectOptionByText(By.id("issue_assigned_to_id"), "<<me>>")
        .selectOptionByText(By.id("issue_custom_field_values_7"), "QA")
        .setText           (By.id("issue_custom_field_values_27"), "Test")
        .setText           (By.cssSelector("*#attachments_fields > span > input:nth-child(1)"), "D:\\NEC new\\log\\EASCrash.txt")
        .click             (By.cssSelector("*#attachments_form > span:nth-child(2) > a"))
        .setText           (By.cssSelector("*#attachments_fields > span:nth-child(2) > input"), "D:\\NEC new\\log\\crash_info_201304171712.txt")
        .click             (By.cssSelector("input[name='issue[watcher_user_ids][]'][value='102]"))
        .click             (By.cssSelector("form#issue-form > input:nth-child(1)"));
    }
}
```

You won't have to worry about the implicit waits like that.. it's all handled by the framework.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"))
```

It seems there are problems with the CSS selector but using XPath should work.

Comment: He's not using a class name, he's using a tag name. In both cases `By.className()` and `By.tagName()` are better alternatives. Anyway, it's strange that the CSS selector does not work. Have you seen any browser rejecting them?

Comment: Good point @Slanec, I've modified my example to represent that. Whether `className()` and `tagName()` are better is open to discussion; personally I like XPath because it is very flexible, much more so than CSS.

Comment: don't **ever** recommend xpath over CSS.  What you can accomplish with xpath, you can accomplish with CSS.. not to mention CSS is faster, cleaner, and just.. better.  Besides, xpath:`//select` and CSS:`select` equate to the same thing.

Comment: I would have to disagree with both of you.  There are a few cases where what you want to do is only possible with XPath, but only in those cases would I recommend it over CSS.  If the CSS selector isn't working, then something else is going wrong (as the error is showing).